# VirtualBox stuck in 800x600 resolution (Arch Linux - KDE Plasma)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, arch-linux, kde

Running KDE Plasma on Arch Linux on VirtualBox.

The desktop is stuck in 800x600 resolution. If I try to set the resolution inside System Settings - Display Configuration, the window enlarges then snaps back to 800x600. I've verified that VirtualBox guest additions are setup and running.

I tried fiddling with VirtualBox's Display settings:

- Video Memory: 128 MB (max)
- VMSVGA w/o 3D Acceleration: stuck in 800x600.
- VMSVGA w/ 3D Acceleration: stuck in 800x600, fonts are messed up and unreadable.
- VBoxVGA: automatically enlarges screen (yay), but constant screen flickering and unusably slow.
- VboxSVGA: same as VBoxVGA

What should I do to be able to set the resolution of the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need install  VM VirtualBox Extension Pack depending of the version of vbox you have and check if guest additions are correctly instaled  if that dont work share more info about your system

Comment: After installing the Extension Pack, VboxSVGA works much better (enlarged screen, no flickering, not slow). Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

So, the extension pack did not work for me...but [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/g8bfeg/fyi_how_to_make_kde_plasma_work_at_resolutions/) did.  It looks like this is a bug with kscreen, at least in my case. Once you remove that package, you can resize the screen with `xrandr -s wwwwxhhh`